# Ghostscript error

Tags: php, pdf, command-line, ghostscript

I'm just trying to make one pdf from another with command line like this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o new.pdf old.pdf
```

And I get the error:

> GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
>
> Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
>
> This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
>
> Error: /undefined in --run--
>
> Operand stack:
>
> --dict:1/1(L)--   Nums
>
> Execution stack:
>
> %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>
> Dictionary stack:
>
> --dict:1161/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:292/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:25/32(L)--
>
> Current allocation mode is local
>
> GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

If I use Multivalent.jar to resize this PDF for example it works fine and resizes it. But GS gives out an error. I need to use GS for this case but I don't get this error occurs. Can I pass it somehow? Or what can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to try to split the problem in half. First try to image the .pdf to the display output, rather than to a .pdf. Next try to read an example .ps file and output a .pdf. Third try a different .pdf than the one you are needing. This will test if ghostscript is properly installed and if the .pdf itself might be the problem. For anyone else to help, a sample file would be needed to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I've posted my question to [http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693929](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693929) and got an answer there that it was a GS bug. So I just downgraded my GS version to 9.06 and this problem has gone

Answer (score 3):

Why not open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com ?